# Running Multiple Linq Queries Async

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out how to use `async`/`await` correctly in the Data Layer of my application to do multiple database calls in parallel.

I am using Entity Framework and Linq to do my data calls.

The Data Layer can be called from any application type (MVC Web App, Web API Project, Win From, Windows Service etc.) - therefore the result of the method should be a single object.

```
    public static async void GetLedger(long id, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        var task_1 = DoComplexDBCallAsync1();
        var task_2 = DoComplexDBCallAsync2();
        var task_3 = DoComplexDBCallAsync3();
        var task_4 = DoComplexDBCallAsync4();
        var task_5 = DoComplexDBCallAsync5();

        await Task.WhenAll(task_1, task_2, task_3, task_4, task_5);

        var result = ProcessAndMergeResultsFromAllDBCalls(task_1.Result, task_2.Result, task_3.Result, task_4.Result, task_5.Result);

        return result;
    }

    private static async Task<List<SomeComplexType>> DoComplexDBCallAsync1(long id)
    {
        using (var metadata = DataAccess.getDesktopMetadata())
        {
            var accounts = await (from row in metadata.db_GLAccount
                                  where row.busID == id
                                  select row).ToListAsync();

            return accounts;
        }
    }
```

How would I change the above to return a single `object` instead of a `Task<>`?

Would I need to wrap it in another method which calls the `GetLedger` async method via a `Task` run or `RunSynchronously()` and returns the results?
If so how would the code look and is there anything I need to be aware of?

What is best practice in this scenario?

Comment: The answer is **you don't**.  It should return a `Task`, not be `void` or return an actual item.  That's what enables it to properly work asynchronously.  If you want it to run synchronously then just create an entirely synchronous method using the synchronous EF code all the way down.

Comment: No.  They'll need to be asynchronous themselves, and be able to see that this method is asynchronous.  Using `await` makes implementing that asynchrony much easier, but it still needs to be there.

Answer (score -1):

You would use await as follows

```
    public static async Task<SomeObject> GetLedger(long id, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        var task_1 = DoComplexDBCallAsync1();
        var task_2 = DoComplexDBCallAsync2();
        var task_3 = DoComplexDBCallAsync3();
        var task_4 = DoComplexDBCallAsync4();
        var task_5 = DoComplexDBCallAsync5();

        var result = ProcessAndMergeResultsFromAllDBCalls(await task_1, await task_2, await task_3, await task_4, await task_5);

        return result;
    }
```

The 'await' keyword will automatically get the result of the Task and apply it to the variables when the DB calls return. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

You would then call

```
var result = await GetLedger(id, StartDate, EndDate);
```

which would proceed after everything is complete.

Comment: You've altered the method from one that does all 5 DB operations in parallel to one that does them all sequentially, and there's every indication that they ought to be done in parallel.  He also specifically asked how to have this method *not* return a `Task`.

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry. I put await in the wrong spot. Edited.